# Docker compose, connect to the container from windows host

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am learning docker so please be understanding.

### My environment config

- I am working on windows (`8 64-bit`)
- I have `Docker toolbox` (as well as `kitematic` but I'm using `quickterminal` only)
- Docker version:

  - Client: `18.03.0-ce`
  - Server: `18.06.0-ce`
- docker machine: `ip:192.168.99.100`
- Let's assume I have the following kibana image `docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.3.2`

---

### Creating a container: 1 - by `run` command and 2 - by `docker-compose`

**1**. `docker container run -p 5601:5601 <image_name>` (let's skip other
            flags and settings for now)

When `http://192.168.99.100:5601` issued on the windows side it connects me to the `default` docker machine running on virtualbox and by providing `-p <docker_host>:<container>` mapping it (`libnetwork`?) redirects my call to the `kibana` container, thus I am **able to connect to the container from windows host**.

`docker container inspect <container_name>` tells me that the default `bridge` network is used. It means that everything works like it supposed to:

```
"NetworkSettings": {
            (...)
            "Ports": {
                "5601/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "5601"
                    }
                ]
            },
            (...)
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "7(...)1",
                    "EndpointID": "3(...)4",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "0(...)2",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
```

**2**. I would like to achieve the same by `docker-compose`. Let's skip meaninglessness of that example for a moment - like I said it's just for my learning purposes.

```
version: "2" 

services:
    kibana:
        container_name: kibana
        hostname: kibana
        image: "docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.3.2"
        volumes:
         - ./kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
        ports:
         - "5601:5601"
        networks:
         - tmp_net
networks:
  tmp_net:
    driver: bridge
```

Let's bring that up by `docker-compose up`. In the output of `docker network ls` command I can see that it created a new network `id:src_tmp_net` with `driver:bridge` and `scope:local`. Inspecting new network I get:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "src_tmp_net",
        "Id": "4(...)6",
        "Created": "2018-08-14T19:59:50.269922334Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.27.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.27.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "7(...)c": {
                "Name": "kibana",
                "EndpointID": "d(...)f",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1b:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.27.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

I am **not able to connect to kibana from windows host** to `http://192.168.99.100:5601` like I could when I created a container by `docker container run (...)` command.

I believe the problem is in the new network (`src_tmp_net`) that was created. Is there a missing config in docker machine for `172.27.0.0/16` pool?

### Question

Why I can't connect to the container created by the aforementioned `docker compose` from my windows host?

---

**EDITED (14.8.18 - 21:37 Z):**

As requested in the comments. [Here](https://justpaste.it/6xsik) are logs after starting `kibana` container. It was logged by `docker-compose up > kibana_logs.txt`.

---

### Answer (in my case)

It was exactly what Mr. @lvthillo pointed out - `kibana.yml` file. In the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.3/docker.html) (for version `6.3`) under the `Docker default` section we can find:

> The following settings have different default values when using the
>   Docker images: (...) **server.host: "0"** (...). These settings are
>   defined in the default kibana.yml. They can be overridden with a
>   custom kibana.yml or via environment variables. Important. **If
>   replacing kibana.yml with a custom version, be sure to copy the above
>   defaults to the custom file if you want to retain them. If not, they
>   will be "masked" by the new file.**

In the [kibana server properties](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/4.5/kibana-server-properties.html) we can find out what exactly `server.host:` is:

> This setting specifies the IP address of the back-end server.

That gives a little light what was happening in my case:

1. My first approach (`docker container run (...)`) worked because I
   didn't specify `volume` to mount and docker container used
   non-persistent storage and - according to aforementioned spec - used
   default
   `kibana.yml` file.
2. My second approach (`docker-compose`) didn't work because I have specified/mounted my own `kibana.yml` file without `server.host:` setting. It overwritten the default file, and because I didn't specified the default settings in there (`server.host:` especially) I wasn't able to connect.

Comment: what is docker logs showing for the container after starting it with docker-compose?

Comment: Updated my question. Of course there is no connection with `elasticsearch` but I believe that is not a problem if my goal is to connect to the container only.

Comment: Did you try it without mounting the kibana.yml file? For me your compose file works (but I didn't mount anything)

Comment: thank you Sir. You were right. I've updated my question with an answer but If you put your comment as an answer I will definitely mark that.